# Magento : Do not want to Load Calendar CSS or Merge with All CSS Files

Tags: magento-1.9, css, calendar, merge-css

I am try to get rid of `calendar.css` file, because I don't use dates anywhere. When I set merge css files from admin, calendar file still loaded separately.

I am just wondering, How can get rid of it completely?

Yes, I could just delete the code but browser still makes 1 extra request to load the blank file.

Magento: 1.9

/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css

Comment: you are talking about admin side or frontend side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly erase `calendar.css`, you need to create a module. Inside your layout update xml file, you need to add this:

File : `app/design/{frontend|adminhtml}/base/default/layout/{layout_update_xml_file}.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Here I am not sure from which area you want to erase those calendar related js/css files. So use either `frontend` or `adminhtml` according to your need.

Comment: Yes I know :-) Happy to help you out.