# Can't get rid of calendar-win2k-1.css via layout xml updates

Tags: magento-1.9, css, layout-update, calendar

I am trying to get rid of a css file, which constantly is being loaded but I don't use dates anywhere in the frontend. It seems I can't erase this file no matter what but it blocks my rendering on each site...

Yes, I could just delete the code of the css file but my browser would still make one extra request to load the blank file.

/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css

I tried editing the local.xml of my own theme to remove this file:

```
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action>
     </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

But that does not change a thing. Then I saw the same problem with a possible solution and tried to copy it:

I tried [Rajeev's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157790/44064) approach to create a module and remove the file in an own custom layout update, however even though my module and custom layout update work (I have succesfully tried adding other example files in the head with my module), the file won't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try :

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    <catalogsearch_advanced_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_index>
</layout>
```

For some reason, it doesn't work with the `default` handle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried but that did not fix it, I also think that the css path is already covered via the <type> declaration.

Comment: Well, I was thinking like you for the css path. But I looked in some of my own project, and it works only if I add it. Oh ! I think I got it : as your file in in the `js` folder : could you try with `js` instead of `css`?

Comment: Also tried this alteration but no effect either...

Comment: I tried with a Magento 19.3.6 version. It seems that it's not working as expected on the `default` handle but it's working on the `catalog_product_view` handle. I update my answer again with something that worked for me.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, do you want to elaborate?